# Get the value of dynamically added textbox

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've a table where I dynamically add textbox and button, also an ajax function that returns a value by sending the textbox string to the controller where it does all the processing.
The code works fine if it's just a single textbox but adding N textbox doesn't work, what should I modify to make the ajax function work with each desired textbox? That is to say
If I want to send the value that is in textbox #2 with its respective button and when clicking on it (btnSearch), what is in textbox #2 is sent and not in number #1

Table code

```
<a href="#" id="addNew" style="text-align:right;float:right"><input type="button" value="Add record" style="height: 30px;width: 110px;font-size: 0.75em" /></a>
<table id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            int i = 0;
            //foreach (var p in Model.TBHDR)
            for (i = 0; i < Model.TBHDR.Count && i < Model.TBDTL.Count; i++)
            {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(mod => mod.TBHDR[i].PR_REQ_OWNER, new { id = "hdr_req_owner", @class = "own" })<input type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch" /></td>
            <td><a href="#" id="remove" class="remove" name="pr_remove">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
            }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Ajax function

```
                $('#dataTable').on('click', '#btnSearch', function (e) {
                  $.ajax({
                  url: "@Url.Action("GetOwner", "PR_Creation")",
                  data: { ownerName: $('#hdr_req_owner').val() },
                  type: "GET",
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (data) {
                    $('#hdr_req_owner').val(data)
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Failed! Please try again.");
                }
            });
            });
```

Edit 1:
Add render elements
[image]

Comment: use classes instead with iterable variable ```i``` and get the event attached to that class. you have like 3-4 elements with same id. it is giving you the first it found. you can't have multiple elements with same id. can you show ispect element of rendered elements?

Comment: @JanatbekOrozaly Added a picture of the render

Comment: NEVER use Form elements like `<input>` inside Action anchor elements like `<a>`. If you need an Anchor -go for it. If you need an Input - that's another story. Semantics and markup matter. Specially *valid* ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('#hdr_req_owner').val() this function always return only first  element in DOM. so always you are getting first input value.

Don't repeat same ID use classes etc..

try to catch the parent of button on click and than use jQuery find method to get the input field. hope it will work.

```js
   $('#dataTable').on('click', '#btnSearch', function (e) {
                let input_field_value = $(this).parents('tr').find(
                '#hdr_req_owner').val();
                  $.ajax({
                  url: "@Url.Action("GetOwner", "PR_Creation")",
                  data: { ownerName: input_field_value },
                  type: "GET",
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (data) {
                    $('#hdr_req_owner').val(data)
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Failed! Please try again.");
                }
            });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesnt work :(

Comment: console $(this).parents('tr').find('#hdr_req_owner').val() what you get?

Comment: or use this 
console $(this).parent('td').find('#hdr_req_owner').val() what you get?

Comment: Almost work with <td> but how can I put the result on the current textbox? because all searches put in the first textbox $('#hdr_req_owner').val(data)

Comment: change a bit. i am writing code here.

$('#dataTable').on('click', '#btnSearch', function (e) {
let _this = $(this); let input_field_value = _this.parents('td').find('#hdr_req_owner').val();
                  $.ajax({url: "@Url.Action("GetOwner", "PR_Creation")",data: { ownerName: input_field_value },type: "GET",dataType: "json",
                  success: function (data) {_this.parents('td').find("#hdr_req_owner").val(data);},
                error: function () {alert("Failed! Please try again.");}
            });
            });

Answer (score 0):

So as I mentioned in the comment, you need to find which element clicked, and use that element.

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")

// handle click and add class
banner.on("click", (event) => {
  const name = event.target.dataset.name;
   $.ajax({
     url: `https://api.github.com/users/${name}`,
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {
       event.target.innerText += data.public_repos
     },
     error: function () {
       alert("Failed! Please try again.");
     } 
     })
   })
jQuery($ => {
    const names = ['janatbek', 'ashley', 'david'];
    for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    banner.append(`<button class="change-color" data-name="${names[i]}">number of public repos of ${names[i]} : </button>`);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("document").ready(() => {` ? Rather use: `jQuery($ => {`

Comment: yeah, it's been a while I used jquery, just quick google and had to have something rolling. but, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Another thing, makes no sense to fetch elements like `var banner = $("#banner-message")` and only after use a DOM ready function like `jQuery($ => {`. Either wrap your code into it or don't use DOM ready at all (Presumably you're calling your scripts where needed, either deferred or right before the closing `</body>` tag)

Comment: OP will figure this out. the important part is where he calls ajax, and uses returned data to put in right place.